# Calling multiple Ajax functions in conjunction with SetInterval

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, promise, setinterval

I have a set of printers associated with different devices. Every 20 seconds I check the status of the printers and display their status (offline, online, out of paper, etc.). User can select a device from a "Devices" dropdown and get status of printers associated with that device; the default on page load is "all devices".

So, there are two parts to getting status: get list of printers for selected device; get status for that list of printers.

To do this I use setInterval function within which I call an Ajax function to get the status.

I am having trouble getting two ajax functions (get device's printers and get printers' status) working in conjunction with setInterval. Getting the list of printers needs to be done once (or until device is changed), getting status needs to be done every 20 seconds.

I think using promise is the way to do it (I could be wrong) but it doesn't work properly. I need some expert assistance.

This is what I have tried but it seems both ajax functions are executed every 20 seconds.

```
var statusParameters;
var printers = [];
var mpeName;
var v;
var pm;

function printer(idn, hostName, ipAddress) {
    this.IDN = idn;
    this.HostName = hostName;
    this.IPAddress = ipAddress;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    statusParameters = {
        interval: 20000,
        interval_id: 0,
        intervalDetail_id: 0,
    };
    ...
    mpeName = '';  // denotes all printers; when user selects a device this value changes
    fetchStatusData();

    statusParameters.interval_id = setInterval(function () {
        fetchStatusData()
    }, statusParameters.interval);

    // Get list of printers for selected device
    pm =
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'Services/ps.asmx/GetPrinterMappingCfg',
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ MPEName: mpeName }),
        }).done(function (result) {
            jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);

            $.each(jResult, function (index, value) {
                var p = new printer(value.IDN, value.Hostname, value.IPAddress);
                printers.push(p);
            });

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        });
    })

    function fetchStatusData() {
        // I tried to put the above "pm" right here too

        $.when(pm)  
            .done(function (r1) {
                $.each(printers, function (index, value) {
                    var currPrinter = value;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Services/ps.asmx/GetPrinterStatus",
                        cache: false,
                        //data: "",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ PrinterIPAddress: currPrinter.IPAddress }),
                    }).done(function (result) {
                        // initial display or updating of status info
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
                        ...
                    });
                });
                printers.length = 0;  // because every 20 sec. it retrieves printer list!
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
              ...
            });
```

The problem I am trying to solve is I want the retrieving of list of printers to be done once, or until user selects a different device not every 20 seconds. It is a waste to keep getting the same printer list every 20 seconds.

Also, the way it is now, on initial page load it does not display printers and their status but will after 20 seconds. It will print on initial load if I move "pm" inside of "fetchStatusData" function.

**Update**

I think I might not have explained what I am trying to do properly. Basically, this is what I am after:

```
Given list of devices in a dropdown list, with "All Devices" selected on page load
Get list of printers for selected device from dropdown
Repeat the following every 20 seconds
    Get status of each printer in list of printers

When user selects a new device, get list of printers again
```

I was thinking another way might be to create a array of "device" objects, each having an array of printer objects in addition to other properties like DeviceID, etc.

This is done only once on document.ready(). Then when a new device is selected, I already have the list of printers and can get it that way. Still would get stuck in setInterval portion of it.

Comment: my immediate problem is avoiding the call to get list of printers ever 20 seconds. Once it is fetched initially, or upon device selection change, there is no need to keep calling it. List doesn't change, only status of the printers change.

Comment: I am sorry, I fail to see how that changes things. When fetchStatusdat is caled every 20 seconds, isn't it going to wait for "pm", which is going to get the list of printers, again? and again 20 seconds later?

Comment: isn't that what you want? you want the POST to `Services/ps.asmx/GetPrinterMappingCfg` to be complete before the first call to `fetchStatusData`? - oh , you already do that, didn't notice ... sorry - let me re-read the question to see if I can see what the problem is

Comment: `it seems both ajax functions are executed every 20 seconds` - can you see them both being requested in the browser developer tools? the code you've posted will definitely only request `Services/ps.asmx/GetPrinterMappingCfg` once - perhaps your code is different to what you posted

Comment: the line `printers.length = 0` will result in `fetchStatusData` only called once, because after it is called, you clear the list of printers, and never populate that array again

Comment: Maybe my understanding of promise is wrong but wouldn't "pm" be called every 20 seconds when fetchStatusData is called. It is using "$.when (pm) ...". Also, in the code that is currently running "pm" is inside "fetchStatusData()" followed by "$.when(pm)...". This works fine except every 20 seconds I am fetching list of printers all over again.

Comment: no, a function is called when you call it only - nothing at all to do with promises - pm is a Promise ... `$.when(pm)` resolves when that one single promise resolves ... but you can call `$when(pm)` over and over, but it's a single promise that resolves once

Comment: Even a pseudocode for doing "when func1 is done, do func2; when func1 and func2 are done, do func3." func2's parameter is one of returned values of func1 and func3's parameter is one of the returned values of func2. func3 needs to run every x seconds. I need to know how to setup these ajax calls so they don't trip over each other.